# Create Keys, Certificates and CA Certificates in windows for RabbitMQ using OpenSSL

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, rabbitmq, certificate

I was using User/Password for connecting to RabbitMQ from client to server.

Recently, our network team raised an issue to disable cleartext authentication.

To resolve this issue, I am planning to create CA Certificates, Certificates (Client and Server) and keys using OpenSSL.

Use these certificates for configuring RabbitMQ server in my machine first and test it thoroughly before we push it higher environments.

I am completely new to OpenSSL and how to create certificates.

I want to now how to create

- Certificate Authority
- Server certificate and Client certificates
- Key

I went to through the below link but I believe OS used is Unix. We want in Windows
https://rabbitmq.docs.pivotal.io/37/rabbit-web-docs/ssl.html

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`tls-gen`](https://github.com/michaelklishin/tls-gen) project to do what you need, but you will eventually want to extend what it does for real world scenarios. This project should work on Windows if you have Python 3 and OpenSSL in your `PATH`